# Protobuf-net Error:Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Data.DataTable

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net, serialization

I need to serialize a datatable which i create during runtime using ProBuf.Serializer which is available under protobuf-net Nuget. Attached below code sample i have used. I am getting error on 
ProtoBuf.Serialzer.Serialize(stream, table); Could somebody help me to sort out this?

```
public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\POC\Test\GrpcServer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\GrpcServer.exe";
            process.Start();
            List<ChannelOption> channelOptions = new List<ChannelOption>()
            {
                new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.MaxSendMessageLength, int.MaxValue)
            };
            Channel channel = new Channel("localhost:5005", ChannelCredentials.Insecure, channelOptions);
            var client = new TestingService.TestingServiceClient(channel);
            DataTable table = CreateTable(100000);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Serialization");
            DateTime serializationStartTime = DateTime.Now;

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, table);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            DateTime serializationEndTime = DateTime.Now;
            byte[] arr = stream.ToArray();
            ByteString data = ByteString.CopyFrom(arr);
            Console.WriteLine("Completed Serialization");
            Console.WriteLine("Started Communication with Grpc Server");
            DateTime startGrpcTime = DateTime.Now;
            client.RecieveData(new PBData() { Data = data });
            DateTime endGrpcTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Grpc communication ended");
            Console.WriteLine($"Serialization time :{(serializationEndTime - serializationStartTime).TotalSeconds}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Grpc Communication time :{(endGrpcTime - startGrpcTime).TotalSeconds}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error:{ex.Message}");
        }
    }`
```

Comment: After posting my answer, I stumbled across this: https://github.com/dotarj/protobuf-net-data - note: this is **not my code** - I have never used it, evaluated it, reviewed it, or anything - so it is not an official recommendation: but: at a cursory glance, it looks like it might do what you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: a lot of the answer below makes the assumption that you are using protobuf-net.Grpc; upon re-reading the post, that might not be a valid assumption - although it would actually work nicely in your case! but: maybe a simpler solution in your case is just to replace the code with:

```cs
DataTable table = CreateTable(100000);
Console.WriteLine("Starting Serialization");
DateTime serializationStartTime = DateTime.Now;

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
table.RemotingFormat = RemotingFormat.Binary;
table.WriteXml(stream);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // not actually needed, note
DateTime serializationEndTime = DateTime.Now;
byte[] arr = stream.ToArray();
ByteString data = ByteString.CopyFrom(arr);
Console.WriteLine("Completed Serialization");
```

(when the author of a library says "it might not be the best choice in your case", you should *probably* listen )

---

protobuf-net is a contract serializer - it helps serialize *data contract* types (in the general sense - not in the WCF-specific sense). `DataTable` is the *opposite* of a data contract - it has no predictable defined shape, so it doesn't play very nicely with protobuf-net. I have historically made *experimental* attempts at allowing them to be serializable - there are some [bits here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/tree/master/assorted/DataTableSerializer), but that is *not* part of the supported library surface of protobuf-net, and frankly: expect it to fail.

I would also note that personally: I'd strongly advise **against** using `DataTable` to exchange data - it is almost never the right type *unless* you are writing an ad-hoc query system, such as a reporting tool or something that works like SSMS/SEDE - i.e. takes some query language and returns some shape of data that cannot be known in advance.

But: that's a side topic, and may be out of your control, so: let's talk `DataTable`:

I think we should forget about the "protobuf-net" part here, and focus on what you're actually trying to do. I'm going to read between some lines here and guess that what you're *actually* after is: you're using protobuf-net.Grpc, and you want to exchange either a `DataTable` or a `DataSet`. The good news is: protobuf-net.Grpc isn't actually tied to protobuf-net **in any way** (except as a default). You can add your own marshaller-factory (or factories) that work against any *category* of types, or for a single type, you can just *give it a marshaller*, for example - completely untested, but this should work:

```cs
ProtoBuf.Grpc.Configuration.BinderConfiguration.Default.SetMarshaller(
    new Marshaller<DataTable>(SerializeDataTable, DeserializeDataTable));

// side note: you may want to try setting the RemotingFormat of the
// DataTable you are using to Binary before sending it to gRPC
static byte[] SerializeDataTable(DataTable value)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    value.WriteXml(ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
static DataTable DeserializeDataTable(byte[] value)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream(value);
    var obj = new DataTable();
    obj.ReadXml(ms);
    return obj;
}
```

Note that you'd need to tell both the client and the server about the custom marshaller.

Note also: the *marshaller* choice is made by protobuf-net.Grpc based on the data going over the service - by which I mean: the parameter type for data being sent, and the return type for data being received. This means that the above only works if `DataTable` is one of those two; so these would work:

```cs
ValueTask<SomeContractType> SendAsync(DataTable blah);
ValueTask<DataTable> ReceiveAsync(SomeContractType blah);
ValueTask<DataTable> SendAndReceiveAsync(DataTable blah);
```

but this would not:

```cs
ValueTask<HazDataTable> WrappedAsync(HazDataTable blah);
// ...
[ProtoContract]
public class HazDataTable {
    [DataMember(1)]
    public DataTable TheData {get;set;}
}
```

because in the `Wrapped` case, protobuf-net.Grpc resolves the marshaller for `HasDataTable` **and never looks inside it** - which means the marshaller would be protobuf-net - and protobuf-net doesn't work with `DataTable`.

Comment: Thanks for a helpful response Marc. Could you able to tell me, is there any way to send larger datatables, say table having row of 10 million, serialize and sending to grpc server on minimal time.  Do you have any idea on sending bulk data between client and server in minimal time?

Comment: @SankarSai "send less data" usually works for me... but: I'm not sure what the specific question is here? Certainly, binary encodings like protobuf are quite good for that, but if you're sending very large payloads you may want to use *streaming* in gRPC, sending the data in batches (of, say, 1k or 10k rows per batch - not individual rows); if you're using protobuf-net.Grpc: that means using `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`